# Enable to use GPU on tensorflow docker image in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, cudnn

I am currently trying to run a tensorflow/keras model using the CuDNNLSTM() layer in a jupyter notebook and nothing works.

When I launch the following docker image, tensorflow/tensorflow:lastest-gpu-py3-jupyter, with this piece of code :

```
nvidia-docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --rm -v $(PATH):/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

I can access the jupyter notebook and it works well. But when I try to execute my model :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], 
train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

with the following import :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, CuDNNLSTM
```

I got this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernelwas registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by node cu_dnnlstm_1/CudnnRNN (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py:517) with these attrs: [dropout=0, seed=87654321, input_mode="linear_input", T=DT_FLOAT, direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", is_training=true, seed2=0]
Registered devices: [CPU, XLA_CPU]
Registered kernels:
     <no registered kernels>

[[node cu_dnnlstm_1/CudnnRNN (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py:517) ]]
```

Has anyone already had this issue on Ubuntu ?

PS : I have installed all tehe pre-requisites (Nvidi cuda, nvidia cudnn, nvidia docker) on my machine.

Comment: Have you try to replace --runtime=nvidia for --gpus all ?. Thus, the command to start the docker should be: docker run --gpus all -it --rm -v $(PATH):/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter